# How to loop through the pages? I am trying to web scrape the page

Tags: javascript, python, excel, web-scraping

How can I scrape the following website, https://www.itf.gov.hk/en/project-search/search-result/index.html?isAdvSearch=1&Programmes=TVP? It is JavaScript. I am trying to get the info in each links in that web site into one excel file.
I was trying to read a excel file with every links in it. Then loop through the excel file. But I cannot do it correctly. The following code can only read the last link and give the data of that link. Where is the problem? Or is there any other way to do it?

```
from tkinter import X
import openpyxl
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import pandas as pd

links = []

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('a.xlsx')
sheet = wb.active              #for reading the excel files
 
for x in range(1,12319,1):
   links.append(sheet.cell(x,2).value)  
   print("size of links = ", len(links))

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36",
    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml; q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8"
}
for i in range(0,12319):
    url = links[i]
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install())
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep (2)

# getting the name of the line and its content
data = {}
index_elem = 1
while True:
    # through the lines until we reach the non-existent
    try:
        columns_name = driver.find_element(
            By.XPATH, f'//*[@id="projectProfile"]/table/tbody/tr[{index_elem}]/th').text
        columns_content = driver.find_element(
            By.XPATH, f'//*[@id="projectProfile"]/table/tbody/tr[{index_elem}]/td').text
        data[columns_name] = [columns_content]
        index_elem += 1
    except NoSuchElementException:
        break

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.to_excel('tvp.xlsx')
```

Comment: is your issue resolved with Sheyteo answer? let us know if you need any help here

Comment: Oh my issue isn't resolved yet. Beacuse the page is a javascript. I cannot use the class tag to search the link.

Comment: can you explain in brief what exactly do you need from the page here

Comment: Inside the link I sent, there is more links in it, e.g. https://www.itf.gov.hk/en/project-search/project-profile/index.html?ReferenceNo=TVP/2122/22. The data I want is the table in this page but I can't loop through all this page to get the data.

Comment: IIUC, for all the projects inside this page `https://www.itf.gov.hk/en/project-search/search-result/index.html?isAdvSearch=1&Programmes=TVP` you want to scrape the data, can you tell us what fields are you interseted in this page

Comment: I only able to get one with my code. I don't know if it helps but I have a excel file contains all links in the search result page. In my code, I was trying to read the excel file and get all links and loop through it. But it failed. I only get the data in the last page.

Comment: The fields I want are Project Reference, Programme, Project Title, Lead Applicant / Name of Company, Project Coordinator / Person-in-charge of Company (PIC), Project Period, Fund Approved, Original Approved Amount, Technological Solution(s)